# Logging queries to H2 database with Play Framework

Tags: logging, playframework, h2, playframework-1.x, h2db

I am using H2 database, in-memory, within Play Framework (1.2.7).

In order to have a log of all queries I added `;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3` at the end of these parameters in Play's `application.conf`:

1. `db.url`
2. `%prod.db.url`
3. `%debug.db.url`

But nithing happens, no file seems to be created or updated on the machine (Mac), even though there is definitely activity with the DB (when I browse to H2's web interface, I can see that many records have been written).

What am I missing? How can I get the log to be written?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE` but you could try using [p6spy](http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/2.0/install.html).

Add the following to your `dependencies.yml`

```
- p6spy -> p6spy 2.1.2:
    exclude:
      - p6spy -> p6spy-signedjar-test
```

The run `play deps`

Now edit your `application.conf' as follows:

```
# Comment out the default test URL
#%test.db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
# Use the p6spy driver
%test.db.driver=com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver
%test.db.url=jdbc:p6spy:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
# Tell the p6spy driver to use the H2 JPA dialect
%test.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Finally, create `conf/spy.properties` and put the following in it:

```
appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.StdoutLogger
realdatasourceclass=org.h2.Driver
```

That's it, you're good to go. Start your app with `play test` and you'll see all database queries logged to stdout.

There are plenty of [other options](http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/2.0/configandusage.html#confusage) that can be configured in `spy.properties`.